# Generating function exponential random graphs with expected number of edges ⟨m⟩

Tags: graph-theory, generating-functions, random-graphs, network

We refers to [Statistical mechanics of networks
by Park and Newman](http://www-eio.upc.edu/~nasini/Blog/Blog_MathematicalSociologyPapers/StatisticalMechanicOfNetworks.pdf)  in the section.   Random graphs Considering exponential random graphs with fixed number of vertices n we know only the expected number of edges $\langle m \rangle$.
We have the adjacency matrix: 
 $$\sigma_{ij}=\begin{cases}
  1  &  \text{if i connected to j} \\
  0 &    \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

To write the degree distribution we can introduce the generating function:
$$g(\alpha)= \sum_{k}p_ke^{\alpha k}$$
After some passages:
$$g(\alpha)= \frac{\sum_{G \in \mathcal{G}}\prod_{k<l}exp[-(\theta+\alpha)\sigma_{kl}]}{(1+ e^{-\theta})^{\binom{n}{2}}} \stackrel{?}{=} \left(\frac{1+ e^{-(\theta+\alpha)}}{1+ e^{-\theta}}\right)^{n-1}$$
Does someone know how the last equality is possible?
In my opinion should be:
$$\frac{\sum_{G \in \mathcal{G}}\prod_{k<l}exp[-(\theta+\alpha)\sigma_{kl}]}{(1+ e^{-\theta})^{\binom{n}{2}}} \stackrel{?}{=} \left(\frac{1+ e^{-(\theta+\alpha)}}{1+ e^{-\theta}}\right)^{\binom{n}{2}}$$